# NetBSD: unable to start KDE because of missing shared objects

Tags: kde, dynamic-linking, shared-library, netbsd

I'm relatively new to UNIX-like OS's, though I know some basic concepts. I managed to build X server and KDE workspace from pkgsrc for my NetBSD 7.0.2. X starts normally, but KDE won't, because it cannot find a shared object named libSM.so.7.

libSM was pulled as dependency during installation of these packages, but there is no file with such a name. Google queries I find on the subject relate to libSM.so.6 which I have. What is this mysterious so.7 I can't grasp.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Did you build KDE from source in pkgsrc, or did install from binary packages?  If from binary packages, did you install the X library sets during the OS install?

Answer (score 0):

First, libSM is the right package and also list .so and so.X files. But Pkgsrc PLIST requires only the static lib entries. Secondly, normally this a problem caused by linking with different versions. When libSM is installed you can find a the right so-files under /usr/pkg/lib. Create a symbolic for libSM.so with ln - s and use as target libSM.so.7.

Comment: Surely, creating a symbolic link should not be necessary?! Something is broken and duct taping it with `ln` is not a good solution. Thanks about the explanation about the `PLIST` though!

Comment: Unfortunately your alternative is to build this package from source.